# Работа с несколькими элементами

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько textdraw с id='chat_text_input', необходимо чтобы данная функция выполнялась не только в одном элементе с chat_text_input, а сразу в нескольких. Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать?

```
<span onclick=\"chat.splace('aa','bb');\">
<img src=\"images/smiles/aa.png\" />
</span>
<textarea name='answer' id='chat_text_input' style='height: 80px'></textarea>

<span onclick=\"chat.splace('ae','bb');\">
<img src=\"images/smiles/ae.png\" />
</span>
<textarea name='answer' id='chat_text_input' style='height: 80px'></textarea>

 var chat = {
    splace: function(s,t) {
        if (t == "bb") s = "[" + s + "]";
          this.mess.value += s;
        },  
        splace2: function(s,t) {
        if (t == "bb") s = "" + s + " ";
          this.mess.value += s;
        },

    init: function() {
          this.mess = document.getElementById("chat_text_input");
        }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
    chat.init();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Не валидно использовать в `html` несколько элементов с одинаковыми `id` лучше вешать класс и получать список элементов при помощи `document.getElementsByClassName` он вернет массив со всеми элементами с указанным классом, в цикле можешь обработать их и делать что надо (:

P.S. Ну если не знаете циклы то и писать на js не стоит а так вот пример (:
[ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/fFSKR/)

html код

```
<form>    
    <textarea class='my-form-textarea' name = 'txt1'></textarea>
    <textarea class='my-form-textarea' name = 'txt2'></textarea>
    <textarea class='my-form-textarea' name = 'txt3'></textarea>
    <input type='button' id='my_button' value='Press'/>
</form>
```

js код

```
var clicked = function(){
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName('my-form-textarea'),
        lngth = list.length,
        i = 0;

    for(;i<lngth;i++){
        list[i].value = 'на всех сразу текст на!';
    }

}

document.getElementById('my_button').onclick = clicked;
```

Comment: Можно на примере пожалуйста, с циклами в js вообще не знаком

Comment: Немного не правильно поставил вопрос. А так все равно спасибо за помощь.
Вопрос: как привязать <span onclick=\"chat.splace('ae','bb');\"> к определенному textarea. Подразумевается что страница имеет вид:

chat.splace('ae','bb');
textarea

chat.splace('ae','bb');
textarea
...

Answer (score 0):

Используйте не id, а class и обращайтесь по классу.